# Using a loop to determine which function to call

Tags: python, class

I have many different methods in a class. Each method contains a function for a unique case. The case is passed to the constructor as a simple integer that identifies which method should be used. 
Is there a better way to set call this function then just a bunch of if statements?

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, case):
        self.__case = case # case is a integer from 1 to 10
        if case == 1:
            self.case1()
        elif case == 2:
            self.case2()
        elif case == 3:
            self.case3() 
        ...
        elif case == 10:
            self.case10():

    def case1(self):
        ...
    def case2(self):
        ...
    def case10(self):
```

The code works but it is very redundant. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are better ways.

If your method names do not follow a pattern but there is a fixed number of them, use a list, then use `case` as an index:

```
cases = [None, self.case1, self.case2, ..., self.case10]
cases[case]()
```

You can build this list up-front with a decorator, but then you'd have to make sure you [bind the function objects to `self`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) first:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, case):
        self._cases[case].__get__(self)()

    def case1(self):
        ...
    def case2(self):
        ...
    def case10(self):
        ...

    _cases = [case1, case2, ..., case10]
```

If your methods really are sequentially numbered, you can generate the method name and use `getattr()` to look up the method:

```
getattr(self, 'case{}'.format(case))()
```